# ¿Cómo formatear un número con 10 dígitos enteros y 6 decimales en PHP?

Tags: php, numberformat

Obtengo un número y necesito que la parte entera del número contenga 10 dígitos, la parte decimal **6** y rellenar lo que falte con **0**.

**Ejemplo:**

```
Numero = 123.54
```

Y necesito que me lo devuelvan así:

```
Numero = 0000000123.000054
```

Intenté con `str_pad($numero, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)` pero el problema es que solo se rellena la parte entera y no puedo con la parte decimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que se pretende aquí a mi juicio es una **modificación** del número, sobre todo porque en la parte decimal, el valor `.54` jamás será igual a `.0054`, en ese caso estarás modificando el valor, lo cual podría tener sus consecuencias, por ejemplo, sumemos:

```
  .54
+ .54
+ .54
-----
  .1612


  .000054
+ .000054
+ .000054
-----------
  .00001612
```

Para fines de redondeo no es lo mismo, pero ese es otro problema.

Simplemente te muestro una forma de hacerlo, mediante el uso de [**`vsprintf`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.vsprintf.php), que admite un array de argumentos. Lo que hacemos simplemente es hacer un `explode` sobre el valor y le indicamos a la función qué formato queremos para cada parte de los números:

#### Código

```
$mNumber=123.54;
echo vsprintf("%010d.%06d", explode('.', $mNumber));
```

#### Salida:

```
0000000123.000054
```

Comment: Felicitaciones es mas precisa su respuesta, no habia trabajado con ese comando: vsprintf()

Answer (score 0):

**OTRA SOLUCION:**

aqui adjunto un codigo para el formateo de numero:

```
<?php



// funcion para conversion especial
function formateoEspecial($entrada, $LongEntero, $LongDecimal) {
    $numero = explode(".", $entrada); // separar entero y decimal
    $Entero = str_pad($numero[0], $LongEntero, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $Decimal = str_pad($numero[1], $LongDecimal, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $salida = $Entero . '.' . $Decimal;
    return $salida;
}

// declaracion de datos
$entrada =  123.54;
$LongEntero =10;
$LongDecimal =6;
// conversion;
$salida = formateoEspecial($entrada, $LongEntero, $LongDecimal);
// salida
echo '<br> numero: ' . $entrada;
echo '<br> salida: ' . $salida;

?>
```

La salida en pantalla es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]